# Navegador desplazable

Tags: html, css

Hola tengo creado un **div** navegador y lo tengo en **position:fixit** porque quiero que me vaya siguiendo todo el rato. Lo que quiero saber como hacer que la barra de navegador baje con la pagina pero que se estacione en la parte de arriba una vez haya llegado a arriba.No sé si me explico pero cualquier duda la contesto.He buscado un duda similar por Stackoverflow y no he encontrado nada parecido, gracias de antemano.

```css
#nav{
 border: solid;
 border-color: cadetblue;
 background: rgba(38, 191, 212, 0.7);
 position:fixed;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   margin-left:-1%;
 margin-right: -1%;
   padding: 0%;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top:0px;
}

#nav li{

   float:left;
   display: inline;
   width:25%;
   list-style: none;
   position:relative; 
 
}

#nav li a{
   color:#666;
   text-decoration:none;
   display:inline;
   font-size:30pt;
 font-family: 'Nanum Pen Script', cursive;
}

#nav li a:hover{
   border:1px black solid;
   color:black;
   border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: skyblue;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#nav li.parent:hover{
   margin:0px;
}
#nav li ul {
  background: rgba(38, 191, 212, 0.7);
 float: none;
   width: 100%;
   margin:0%;
   padding: 0%;
   display:none;
   border:1px black solid;
   position: absolute;
   left: -1px;
   top:100%;
 border-radius: 12px;
   
}
#nav li:hover ul {
   display: block;
 float: none;
}
#nav li li{
   display:block;
 float: none;
    width: 100%;
   margin:0%;
   padding: 0%;
}

#nav li li a{
   display:block;
 float: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url(imagen.JPG);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
 }
 .fondonegrotransparente {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
    h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
.logo
{
 display:inline;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 20%
}
.texto1{
 font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', cursive;
 color:white;
 font-size:3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
 <div class="fondonegrotransparente">
 <h1 class="texto1">EL PAGÈS DE RUBÍ</h1>
 </div>
  <img src="logo%20pages.png" class="logo" width=160px/>
</div>
<ul id="nav">
 <li class="parent"><a href="inicio.html">Inici</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="coneixens.html">Coneixen's</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Varietats que oferim</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="fruites.html">Fruites</a></li>
   <li><a>Verdures</a></li>    
   <li><a>Llegums</a></li>   
   <li><a>Altres</a></li>    
  </ul>
  </li>     
  <li class="parent"><a href="contacta.html">Contacta'ns</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ya que estoy si alguien puede decirme como escribir css y que me lo escriba bien formado se lo agradecería, así me ahorro pedir a la gente que me lo arregle.

Comment: Debes usar la propiedad `top:0` y `left:0` para fijarlo siempre arriba, o bien meter un JS que lo fije cuando se haga scroll. El CSS me parece que es mucho pedir que te lo reescriban bien formado, es algo que debes hacer tu a base de aprendizaje y estudio.

Comment: Si, no pido que me lo reescriban solo como se podría hacer. Respecto a tu respuesta estoy aún aprendiendo, podrías aclararme que es un JS o escribirme lo sin abreviatura para que pueda buscar información al respecto. Gracias.

Comment: JS es un JavaScript. Puedes decir mediante JS que cuando el usuario haga scroll la barra de navegación se fije a la parte superior de la ventana.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Voy a buscar al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas no es un `sticky` nav?

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
</div>
<nav>Navegacion</nav>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
  est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
  irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, qui reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
  deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
  sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, qui
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
  nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
  est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
  irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

Comment: Pero cuando lo implemento en mi código no me funciona, me lo pone fijo y cuando bajo con el scroll no se queda arriba...

Comment: Cambiaste los estilos adecuados?

Comment: Deberias usar las mismas propiedades que defini yo, nada de floats

Comment: Pero si puedo definirlos en los li o ul dentro del nav no es cierto?

Comment: Puedes aplicar los estilos que quieras a los elementos en el nav, pero no recomiendo usar `float` en ninguno de esos casos, siempre puedes utilizar las propiedades de Flexbox y margenes para alinear los elementos en las posiciones que desees, los elementos flotantes se comportan diferente y pueden causar inconsistencias

Comment: pues nada no lo consigo, pero gracias igualmente por tu tiempo invertido en solucionarme la duda...

Comment: Recuerda que puede ser que tengas otro estilo que este alterando el comportamiento, siempre puedes editar tu pregunta original para incluir los nuevos cambios que hayas hecho y talvez asi logremos encontrar donde esta el error